# Failed to execute goal tomcat:deploy Error writing to server

Tags: eclipse, apache, maven, tomcat7

I'm trying to test a spring-mvc tutorial [here](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/).

I would like to deploy the generated war on tomcat 7 using eclipse-maven.

The war works fine when deployed manually on tomcat.

Steps to follow :

- import project on eclipse
- add this plugin to the existing POM:

  ```
  <plugin>
               <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
               <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.1</version>
              <configuration>
                  <mode>war</mode>
                  <url>http://localhost:8080/manager/html/</url>
                  <server>TomcatServer</server>
                  <path>/springexample</path>
                </configuration>
  ```
- configure a new tomcat server in eclipse with the name TomcatServer

modify the tomcat-users.xml file:
include an admin user:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin"/>
    <role rolename="standard"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager"/>
    <role rolename="tomcat"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <user password="password" roles="standard,manager,admin,manager-gui,manager-script,tomcat" username="admin"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

- Add the server configuration to the setting.xml config file under .m2
  user folder:

  TomcatServer
      admin
      password
- Strat tomcat server

When I execute the following goals :

Maven generate-sources : to generate the war file

then Run configuration --> with the goal :

tomcat:deploy

the error is :

[

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy (default-cli) on
>   project springexample: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Error writing to
>   server -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:redeploy
>   (default-cli) on project springexample: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
>     at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)   at
>   org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)  at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)   at
>   org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
>   Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot
>   invoke Tomcat manager     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:149)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractWarCatalinaMojo.java:70)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
>     at
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
>     ... 19 more Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server
>     at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deployImpl(TomcatManager.java:662)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.deploy(TomcatManager.java:295)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployWarMojo.deployWar(AbstractDeployWarMojo.java:85)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractDeployMojo.invokeManager(AbstractDeployMojo.java:85)
>     at
>   org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.AbstractCatalinaMojo.execute(AbstractCatalinaMojo.java:141)
>     ... 22 more [ERROR]  [ERROR]  [ERROR] For more information about the
>   errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
>   [ERROR] [Help 1]
>   http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: Did you find the solution to the problem? I am facing the same issue.

Answer (score 5):

In my case, using the tomcat7 command for deployment worked :

```
tomcat7:deploy
```

And you should not use :

```
tomcat:deploy
```

Answer (score 3):

My issue was related to the fact the WAR file was over 50mb. You need to set the config in web.xml from the tomcat manager.

The file will normally be in %tomcat installation%\webapps\manager\WEB-INF\web.xml

```
<multipart-config>
  <!-- 50MB max -->
  <max-file-size>52428800</max-file-size>
  <max-request-size>52428800</max-request-size>
  <file-size-threshold>0</file-size-threshold>
</multipart-config>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should focus your effors on

```
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error writing to server 
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.writeRequests(Unknown Source)
at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source) 
at org.codehaus.mojo.tomcat.TomcatManager.invoke(TomcatManager.java:604)
```

Look at the source for TomcatManager (http://mojo.codehaus.org/tomcat-maven-plugin/xref/org/codehaus/mojo/tomcat/TomcatManager.html#672)

The maven plugin cannot read from the server. It connects, line 597, it writes the data, line 601, but fails when it reads the response, line 604

I would try to deploy at the server first (to get rid of network problems) and see if the problem persists.